# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies'

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Asp.NET MVC project, database first.
I have an **Create** action in **Place** controller. In the action method I get my data like this:

```
// GET: /Place/Create
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var places = db.Places.Where(p => p.UserId == userId);

    var placesVM = new PlacesVM(places);

    ViewBag.UserId = new SelectList(db.AspNetUsers, "Id", "UserName");
    return View(placesVM);
}
```

My Place view model looks like this:

```
public class PlacesVM
{
    public IQueryable<Place> Places { get; set; }
    public Place Place { get; set; }

    public PlacesVM(IQueryable<Place> places)
    {
        Places = places;
        Place = new Place();
    }
}
```

My Place Model:

```
public partial class Place
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        //TODO: Validare cordonate
        public decimal X { get; set; }
        public decimal Y { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(250, MinimumLength = 5)]
        public string Titlu { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Description")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 10)]
        public string Descriere { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0, 1)]
        public byte Public { get; set; }

        public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    }
```

AspNetUser:

```
public partial class AspNetUser
    {
        public AspNetUser()
        {
            this.AspNetUserClaims = new HashSet<AspNetUserClaim>();
            this.AspNetUserLogins = new HashSet<AspNetUserLogin>();
            this.Places = new HashSet<Place>();
            this.UserComments = new HashSet<UserComment>();
            this.AspNetRoles = new HashSet<AspNetRole>();
        }

        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
        public string Discriminator { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserClaim> AspNetUserClaims { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserLogin> AspNetUserLogins { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Place> Places { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserComment> UserComments { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AspNetRole> AspNetRoles { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I would like to use Model.Places proprietes in the javascript part of the page. How can I do this?

I've tried to the following:

```
<script>
    var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
</script>
```

But I got this error:

`{"A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Place_084A987E8F6FBE574A22E813FE314F2894AF728F244BDD6582AF50929FF1161D'."}`

I have checked the following links on SO, but didn't manage to solve my problem:

- [Use return values only in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615623/use-return-values-only-in-javascript)
- [Serialize EF Object into JSON - ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634494/serialize-ef-object-into-json-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Not related, but It would need to be `var model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));` (without the quotes) if you wanted to serialize the model to a javascript object.

Comment: You need to show the model for `Place` (it would contain a property which is an object that contains a property `Place`, causing a circular reference)

Comment: Does class `AspNetUser` contain a property for `Place`?

Comment: AspNetUser contains: public virtual ICollection<Place> Places { get; set; }

Comment: That's the cause of the problem (serializing `Place` also serializes `AspNetUser` which then serializes its property `Places` which then has to serialize each `Place` which serializes `AspNetUser` and so on and so on - a circular reference). You will need to use a view model  (and should be anyway) with just the properties you need in the view (say) `class PlaceVM` and copy the properties you need from `Place` into it except `AspNetUser`. If you need anything related to `AspNetUser` in the view, just add some properties for it (say) `int UserID` and `string `UserName`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks, I understand now. If you post this, I will accept your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113840/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-stefan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `PlacesVM` view model contains a property that is typeof `Place` which in turn contains a property which is typeof `AspNetUser` which in turn contains a property which is typeof `Collection<Place>`.

When the `Json.Encode()` method serializes you model, it serializes `Place` which then serializes `AspNetUser` which then serializes each `Place` which throws the error, because if allowed to continue, it would serialize each `AspNetUser` and so on and so on until the system ran out of memory.

Change you view model to include only those property that you need in the view - refer [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc). Note that a view model should not generally contain properties which are data models, particularly when you editing data in a view. Instead, copy the properties from `Place` into `PlaceVM` that you need to edit, except `AspNetUser`, and if you need to display some properties of `AspNetUser`, then just include additional properties for then, for example `public string UserName { get; set; }`.

Side note: Your current view model does not contain a default (parameterless) constructor so the `DefaultModelBinder` will throw an exception when you submit.